# How can I set the double-click speed in Lion with a multi-touch trackpad?

Tags: trackpad, system-settings, click

In Snow Leopard and earlier (or perhaps the difference was with the hardware; I don't know which as I updated my computer and OS simultaneously), there was a preference under Trackpad to change the speed needed to perform a double-click. How can I speed it up now that it isn't there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Lion, the trackpad double-click speed slider and a few other trackpad options have been moved to: `System Preferences > Universal Access > Mouse & Trackpad > Trackpad Options`.

[image: Track Pad double click speed]

Comment: So that's where it went! I actually went to that tab of that pane in looking for it, but I didn't click on that button. Silly me. ;)

Comment: No Silly Apple, that makes no sense to be there